# Loading nodes that are only available to the current user

Tags: 7, nodes

How do I programmatically load nodes that are available to the current user?

I used `node_load_multiple()`, but it seems to directly load nodes from the database, bypassing permissions.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to use the `EntityFieldQuery` class](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708). The following is example code to load all the published nodes whose content type is *Article*.

```php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED);

$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);
}
```

EntityFieldQuery returns only the nodes to which the currently logged-in user has access. In the case you would get all the nodes for which you know the author user ID, you should use the following code.

```php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->propertyCondition('uid', $uid);

$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);
}
```

That code returns all the nodes created in the site. To get only 10 nodes, it sufficient to add a call to `$query->range(0, 10)` before calling `$query->execute()`.